# Can't add button under the admob ad

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am trying to add Add a simple button under my admob ad but it doesn't let me

Here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/q1t"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Q:1 How Tall is Mount Everest"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adViewQ1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/q1t"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/adViewQ1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="147dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="147dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:text="This button" />






    </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2jNx.png)

No matter what i try to do the button just doesn't go under ad.
Sorry for the newbie question I am just starting out...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- copy and past this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Q:1 How Tall is Mount Everest"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewQ1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/q1t"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/q1t"
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="This button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adViewQ1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```